# How to display "No Results" using firebase_pagination: ^3.0.0

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using [firebase_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_pagination): ^3.0.0 to display all listings for each category. Some categories currently have 0 listings. When I open up one of them, the screen just shows a never-ending circular progress indicator. I want to display something like "No results yet".

Screenshot:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
class CategoryPaginationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoryPaginationScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.category,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String category;

  @override
  State<CategoryPaginationScreen> createState() =>
      _CategoryPaginationScreenState();
}

class _CategoryPaginationScreenState extends State<CategoryPaginationScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.category),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.sort),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: FirestorePagination(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          limit: 10,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          isLive: true,
          query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('listings')
              .where('category', isEqualTo: widget.category)
              .orderBy('lastUpdated'),
          itemBuilder: (context, documentSnapshot, index) {
            final data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListingItem(listing: Listing.fromMap(data));
          },
          // bottomLoader: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          // separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `onEmpty` property in `firebase_pagination` package to define the widget to show when the query has no results

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked it earlier. However, even after I added the property, the issue still persisted. Then, I found out about adding composite index (lastUpdated Descending dueDate Ascending) in Firebase and now everything works as intended.